# Potential drop in a wire having negligible resistance

Tags: electricity

What causes a potential drop in a resistor or load?  Why a wire having neglible resistance have same potential across it?[image]
The given figure is of a stretched wire potentiometer.
My question is why point a and A have same potential after connection through a wire of negligible resistance.
Before connection there can be different potentials on poinrs a and A. So how the same potential achieved after connection. I wants it's machanism and explanation.

Comment: Related: [Voltage Change Across a Resistor/Circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508607/22927)

Comment: Also [Can resistance of wire be ignored](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103089/22927)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential difference, or voltage, between two points equals the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points. If there is negligible resistance between points a and A, the work required to move charge between the two points (potential difference) is also negligible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why point a and A have same potential after connection through a wire of negligible resistance.

Because $V=IR$. If $R$ is negligible (i.e. $R\approx 0$), then when you multiply it by a finite $I$, the resulting $V$ is also negligible.

> Why a wire having neglible resistance have same potential across it?

This is confusing. First you say there is "same" potential across the wire, but if `a` and `A` are at the same potential, then there is *no* potential across the wire.

> Before connection there can be different potentials on poinrs a and A.

Suppose the resistance of the wire is actually 0.01 ohms. Now suppose there was 1 V across the wire (i.e. 1 V between `a` and `A`). Now how much current is flowing in the wire? Where does that current go after flowing from `a` to `A` or vice versa? There can't be so much current flowing here because that would be inconsistent with the currents and potentials in the rest of the circuit.